# No workspace in jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, devops, workspace

I am trying to build a lambda function in Jenkins, using a docker agent(Hosted in ECR) but at the end of the construction, the workspace is deleted. I need this workspace to use in another build. I attach the error. Can you help me? I understand that at the end of the build, the docker agent is destroyed. Is there any way to change this?

[image]